# Server to client streaming using WebSockets and Netty

Tags: netty

How can I achieve Server to client streaming using WebSockets and Netty?

I have explored websocket sample.
https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/3.2/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example/http/websocketx

Comment: I dont think the following example deals with streaming, but then you can take a look and verify https://github.com/rocketpages/Netty-TicTacToe-Server It uses websockets and jquery and netty.

Comment: Any sample for server to client communication only?

Answer (score 0):

As a first step, I would recommend trying out the examples.

https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/3.2/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example/http/websocketx

Comment: Thanks. I have tried the websocket example. Any pointers on my original question?